# knockout validation with bootstrap - cannot get 'has-error' property to attach to element

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-validation

I think I have most things configured correctly.  I can debug and see that the subscribe options are firing but nothing ever seems to change...

In my viewmodel I have:

```
ko.validation.init({
    errorElementClass: 'has-error',
    errorMessageClass: 'help-block',
    decorateInputElement: true
}, true);

ko.extenders.required = function (target, overrideMessage) {
    //add some sub-observables to our observable
    target.hasError = ko.observable();
    target.validationMessage = ko.observable();

    //define a function to do validation
    function validate(newValue) {
        target.hasError(newValue ? false : true);
        target.validationMessage(newValue ? "" : overrideMessage || "This field is required");
    }

    //initial validation
    validate(target());

    //validate whenever the value changes
    target.subscribe(validate);

    //return the original observable
    return target;
};

var validationMapping = {
    usr_login: {
        create: function (options) {
            return ko.observable(options.data).extend({ required: "Please enter a login for the user" });
        }
    };
```

And I do my data call like so:

```
return dc.getSingleUser(node.data.userID)
    .then(function (data) {
    self.selectedUser(mapping.fromJS(data, validationMapping)); //use mapping
})
```

And the view has:

```
<div class="form-group" data-bind="validationElement: selectedUser().usr_login">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">User Login</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input type="text" data-bind="enable: inEditMode, value:selectedUser().usr_login" class="form-control" placeholder="User login">
     </div>
</div>
```

All debug points seem to be hit, it successfully returns a "false" from the subscribe method when I leave the field blank but the `"has-error"` tag never seems to appear anywhere.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Edit 1:  It's something to do with the `custom extender`.

In desperation I commented out the `ko.extenders.required` function above and all instantly started working. So I suppose the question is... what's wrong with the custom function above?

I note that the custom message I'm providing is being ignored though.

I just get `"this field is required"` instead of `"please enter a login for this user"`.

Edit 2:

Now working with just this and no custom extender.

```
<div class="form-group" data-bind="validationElement: selectedUser().usr_login">
     <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">User Login</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" data-bind="enable: inEditMode, value:selectedUser().usr_login" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name">
     </div>
</div>
```

and

```
var validationMapping = {
    usr_login: {
        create: function (options) {
            var self = this;
            return ko.observable(options.data).extend({ required: { params: true, message: 'You must enter a login name for the user.' } });
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or edit the question so that we can debug and see what is the issue with your code?

Comment: I think you have to add a line in your html like  <p data-bind="css: { error: selectedUser().usr_login.hasError }">

Comment: No, that's not it. It is something to do with the custom extender (which I don't need now) as it was somehow affecting what the system expected back.  I now have it working - see edit 2 above.  The whole point of `validationElement` is to avoid what you're suggesting.

Comment: I'm not sure you're understand my comments. It's fixed and done, there's nothing left to help me with. You were off the mark with your comment about messing with the css binding, that wasn't necessary. Look at Edit 2 in my first post, that explains it.

Answer (score 0):

Now working with just this and no custom extender.

```
<div class="form-group" data-bind="validationElement: selectedUser().usr_login">
     <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">User Login</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" data-bind="enable: inEditMode, value:selectedUser().usr_login" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name">
     </div>
</div>
```

and

```
var validationMapping = {
    usr_login: {
        create: function (options) {
            var self = this;
            return ko.observable(options.data).extend({ required: { params: true, message: 'You must enter a login name for the user.' } });
        }
    }
};
```